# Help with an Arduino-based PC "Ambilight" setup

Tags: power-supply, led

I have been trying to follow [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juC-3imLoTQ) to make a PC ambilight setup.

I am having trouble finding a good power supply (bought an unsafe one from eBay). I have 65 LEDs, so according to that video (and [this link](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/guide-for-ws2812b-addressable-rgb-led-strip-with-arduino/)) I need a 5V 4A DC power supply and associated barrel connector.

First question, because these are PC/arduino-controlled LED strips with an external power source, it's not clear what the LEDs will do when the PC is off. Would it be also possible to include an in-line switch between the power supply and the LEDs?

Second question, an even better improvement, but possibly the most tricky (?) - this LED strip is going to be replacing a lamp. Could I have the LED strip output a single colour (warm-white) that isn't controlled by the PC when desired?

I was hoping to have a 3-way switch setup:

- Off
- Warm-white "lamp mode"
- PC ambilight

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDZzH.jpg) is a photograph of the back of my monitor with the LED strips on showing where the Arduino will sit and the ideal location of the switch.

Comment: your first question is a request for product recommendation, so it is off topic .... however, if you post a link to a specific power supply, then a comment can be made about the suitability of the power supply ....... also, it is unclear how the location of the LED strip and the location of the Arduino and the location of the switch relates to the question

Comment: I have removed the "shopping" part of your question.

Comment: Edited my question to have a product.

Comment: Asking for a product recommendation is still a shopping question, even if you name the product. It's OK to ask about what you should look for in a power supply, but if you limit the question to a specific product then it won't have much value to other people who visit the site.

Comment: Sorry, I linked a specfic product in response to jsotola's comment.